Trying to find an error in app; appears on load
When I launch a canvas app (that seems to function as it should) the following error appear on loading "The value 'Text' cannot be converted to a number.
I understand what the error means, but I cannot find where in the app its referencing. Data loads as it should in the app. Would it be safe to assume the error is on the screen that first loads? Or could that error be on any of the screens? The only time the error banner appears is when you first load the app. Navigating to any of the screens you never see it.
Thoughts?
I assume the error is related to the screen that loads first. There are only a couple of numbers on that page but none of them seem to be the problem.

If this is happening consistently, you can do the following to get more information about this error:

Set the App.OnError property to the following expression:

Collect(appErrors, $"Error: {FirstError.Kind}-{FirstError.Message}, from {FirstError.Source}/{FirstError.Observed}"); Error(FirstError)

Add a label in your app, with the following expression for its Text property:

Concat(appErrors, Value, Char(10))
Then save/publish and open the app again. The new label will show the errors that are unhandled in the app (like the one that you are seeing), alongside the location where it happened, and where it was surfaced to the app (they are often the same, but not necessarily). Once you know where the error is happening, you can take precautions to capture it and prevent it from being unhandled in your app.
